# Nagstamon doesn't show in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, bug-reporting, nagios3

I'm trying to do the `nagstamon` work on Ubuntu 12.04, but after setting my `credentials only`, the other setting I kept default, it doesn't show anywhere.
I'm sure it's running 'cause of `ps aux | grep nagstamon` show me that is running and the sounds that it makes when some status change.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having this problem too, I was able to solve it by getting a `.nagstamon.conf` from a `centOS` machine, just altering the `username` and `password`.

So to fix this, put the `settings`, `credentials` at the first screen of `nagstamon` as you usually do, after that, hit `OK`. It won't open, right ?

Now copy and paste somewhere the field `username` and `password`, `configfile`, `debug_file` and `app_ssh_options` something like:

```
username = eJwFwdEOaiAUANWP6iTEWfmo4VVg11NlL .. // and go on
password = aJwdawadsfcaErfdEtqWfdffaere .. // and go on
configfile = /home/username/.nagstamon.conf
debug_file = /home/username/nagstamon.log
app_ssh_options = -l username
```

Now, kill the process :

```
ps aux | grep nagstamon
```

Create a new `.nagstamon.conf` file in you home folder.

```
vim ~/.nagstamon.conf
chmod 664 ~/.nagstamon.conf
```

Now copy and paste this configuration below and replace the fields the fields mentioned above:

```
[Nagstamon]
connect_by_dns_yes = False
color_down_text = #ffffffffffff
notify_if_unreachable = True
statusbar_systray = False
app_ssh_bin = /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x ssh
color_ok_background = #000064640000
filter_services_on_hosts_in_maintenance = False
default_color_ok_text = #FFFFFF
color_warning_text = #000000000000
update_interval = 1
color_unknown_text = #000000000000
default_color_warning_text = #000000
notification_custom_sound_warning = None
long_display = False
filter_acknowledged_hosts_services = False
color_unknown_background = #ffffa5a50000
debug_mode = False
notify_if_warning = True
filter_services_on_down_hosts = False
notify_if_unknown = True
default_color_critical_background = #FF0000
color_critical_background = #ffff00000000
notification_custom_sound = False
color_critical_text = #ffffffffffff
configfile = /home/<replace>/.nagstamon.conf
notification_sound = True
notification = True
debug_to_file = False
filter_hosts_services_disabled_notifications = False
filter_services_on_acknowledged_hosts = False
default_color_critical_text = #FFFFFF
notify_if_down = True
notify_if_critical = True
popup_details_hover = False
re_service_reverse = False
show_grid = True
re_service_pattern = 
default_color_error_text = #000000
debug_file = /home/<replace>/nagstamon.log
app_rdp_options = -g 1024x768
color_warning_background = #ffffffff0000
unconfigured = False
color_unreachable_background = #8b8b00000000
default_color_unreachable_text = #FFFFFF
notification_custom_sound_critical = None
re_service_enabled = True
default_color_down_background = #000000
default_color_down_text = #FFFFFF
filter_hosts_services_maintenance = False
filter_services_on_unreachable_hosts = False
filter_all_warning_services = False
filter_all_unreachable_hosts = False
default_color_warning_background = #FFFF00
filter_all_down_hosts = False
re_host_reverse = False
color_ok_text = #ffffffffffff
popup_details_clicking = True
re_host_enabled = False
short_display = True
app_vnc_bin = /usr/bin/vncviewer
check_for_new_version = False
re_host_pattern = 
position_y = 4
default_color_ok_background = #006400
position_x = 2164
default_color_unknown_background = #FFA500
notification_default_sound = True
app_ssh_options = -l <replace>
color_error_text = #000000000000
default_color_unknown_text = #000000
filter_all_unknown_services = False
icon_in_systray = False
default_color_error_background = #D3D3D3
default_color_unreachable_background = #8B0000
color_unreachable_text = #ffffffffffff
statusbar_floating = True
notification_custom_sound_down = None
color_error_background = #d3d3d3d3d3d3
notification_flashing = True
filter_hosts_services_disabled_checks = False
app_rdp_bin = /usr/bin/rdesktop
notification_sound_repeat = False
color_down_background = #000000000000
filter_all_critical_services = False
filter_services_in_soft_state = False
connect_by_dns_no = True
app_vnc_options = 
[Server_Default]
username = <replace>
use_proxy = False
name = Default
nagios_cgi_url = <replace>
enabled = True
nagios_url = <replace>
proxy_password = <replace>
save_password = True
proxy_username = <replace>
proxy_address = http://proxy:port/
password = <replace>
type = Nagios
use_proxy_from_os = False
```

If there's any dobut, I will put my `.nagstamon.conf` below so you can see how it should look:

```
    [Nagstamon]
connect_by_dns_yes = False
color_down_text = #ffffffffffff
notify_if_unreachable = True
statusbar_systray = False
app_ssh_bin = /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x ssh
color_ok_background = #000064640000
filter_services_on_hosts_in_maintenance = False
default_color_ok_text = #FFFFFF
color_warning_text = #000000000000
update_interval = 1
color_unknown_text = #000000000000
default_color_warning_text = #000000
notification_custom_sound_warning = None
long_display = False
filter_acknowledged_hosts_services = False
color_unknown_background = #ffffa5a50000
debug_mode = False
notify_if_warning = True
filter_services_on_down_hosts = False
notify_if_unknown = True
default_color_critical_background = #FF0000
color_critical_background = #ffff00000000
notification_custom_sound = False
color_critical_text = #ffffffffffff
configfile = /home/valter.silva/.nagstamon.conf
notification_sound = True
notification = True
debug_to_file = False
filter_hosts_services_disabled_notifications = False
filter_services_on_acknowledged_hosts = False
default_color_critical_text = #FFFFFF
notify_if_down = True
notify_if_critical = True
popup_details_hover = False
re_service_reverse = False
show_grid = True
re_service_pattern = ^OPS
default_color_error_text = #000000
debug_file = /home/valter.silva/nagstamon.log
app_rdp_options = -g 1024x768
color_warning_background = #ffffffff0000
unconfigured = False
color_unreachable_background = #8b8b00000000
default_color_unreachable_text = #FFFFFF
notification_custom_sound_critical = None
re_service_enabled = True
default_color_down_background = #000000
default_color_down_text = #FFFFFF
filter_hosts_services_maintenance = False
filter_services_on_unreachable_hosts = False
filter_all_warning_services = False
filter_all_unreachable_hosts = False
default_color_warning_background = #FFFF00
filter_all_down_hosts = False
re_host_reverse = False
color_ok_text = #ffffffffffff
popup_details_clicking = True
re_host_enabled = False
short_display = True
app_vnc_bin = /usr/bin/vncviewer
check_for_new_version = False
re_host_pattern = 
position_y = 4
default_color_ok_background = #006400
position_x = 2164
default_color_unknown_background = #FFA500
notification_default_sound = True
app_ssh_options = -l valter.silva
color_error_text = #000000000000
default_color_unknown_text = #000000
filter_all_unknown_services = False
icon_in_systray = False
default_color_error_background = #D3D3D3
default_color_unreachable_background = #8B0000
color_unreachable_text = #ffffffffffff
statusbar_floating = True
notification_custom_sound_down = None
color_error_background = #d3d3d3d3d3d3
notification_flashing = True
filter_hosts_services_disabled_checks = False
app_rdp_bin = /usr/bin/rdesktop
notification_sound_repeat = False
color_down_background = #000000000000
filter_all_critical_services = False
filter_services_in_soft_state = False
connect_by_dns_no = True
app_vnc_options = 
[Server_Default]
username = MG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYN=
use_proxy = False
name = Default
nagios_cgi_url = http://nagios.company.com/nagios/cgi-bin
enabled = True
nagios_url = http://nagios.company.com
proxy_password = MG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYN/f0C8W
save_password = True
proxy_username = MG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYN==
proxy_address = http://proxy:port/
password = MG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYNMG24QxTk8TYN ==
type = Nagios
use_proxy_from_os = False
```

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagstamon/files/nagstamon/nagstamon%200.9.11/nagstamon_0.9.11_all.deb/download) is a new stable version available with extra Ubuntu Unity support.